# Understanding services in kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-service

I am studying services in k8s from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors)

I have created service without selector and with one endpoint. What I am trying to do is I have installed apache and it's running on port 80. I have created a node port service on port 31000. Now this service should redirect ip:31000 to ip:80 port.

It is doing for internal ip of service but not on external ip.

**my-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9376
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 31000
  type: NodePort
```

**my-endpoint.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: <IP>
    ports:
      - port: 80
```

Output for **kubectl get service -o wide**

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          53m   <none>
my-service   NodePort    10.111.205.207   <none>        9376:31000/TCP   30m   <none>
```

Comment: How are you running apache? Are you running the apache inside a pod or are you installed in the node directly? Also where are you running this? Minikube or cloud managed kubernetes cluster?

Comment: What do you mean by external IP? Is that an IP that is publicly reachable? NodePort type services make your service available on the cluster nodes using `${NodeIP}:${NodePort}`. If those nodes don't have public IPs, you won't be able to access your service from outside your network.

Comment: I am running Apache on node only. I am running it on a cloud. Cloud has two worker nodes and one master node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing is, you need to run a pod inside your cluster then assign the ip of  that pod inside the Endpoints yaml with port, because services exposes the pods to within or outside the cluster, we must use either selector or the address of the pod so that service can attach it self to particular pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: <ip address of the pod>
    ports:
      - port: <port of the pod>
```

One more thing use Statefulset in place of Deployment to run pods.

Comment: Thanks Arun for the explanation. This has worked for me now.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple types of services which can give you different levels of access:

**ClusterIP** - can access the service from another pod ( only inside the Kubernetes Cluster)

**NodePort** - can access the service from another pod, and from the machine that it is running the Kubernetes cluster

**LoadBalancer** - can access the service from outside the Kubernetes cluster ( using an external IP )

**LoadBalancers** are great when you have a TCP level connection. If you have a higher level connection ( **http** ) you can also use **Ingress** + **NodePort**.

Comment: I was expecting solution for a problem posted in question.i know the theory

Comment: Well, this is the solution... Use the LoadBalancer service type or use an Ingress combined with a NodePort service. How to implement them depends on the cloud provider that you are using. Usually, you can find a lot of documentation on how to use these resources on each cloud provider.

Comment: can you post any example for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Uses of services is to set up communication between all of different pods or to get access to a pod from the outside of cluster.

So every pod or every deployment you create is always going to have some kind of matching service along with it. There are several different kinds of services.

**1. Cluster IP:** Sets up an easy to remember URL to access a pod. Only exposes pods in the cluster. So cluster IP service used anytime that you want to set up communication between different pods inside of your cluster.

for example: event-bus-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: event-bus-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: event-bus
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: event-bus
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: event-bus
          image: lordrafiq/event-bus:latest
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: event-bus-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: event-bus
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: event-bus
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4005
      targetPort: 4005
```

So from inside of any pod you want to communicate with event-bus, you can using event-bus-srv on port 4005.

```
 await axios.post('http://event-bus-srv:4005/events', {});
```

**2. Node Port:** Makes a pod accessible from outside of the cluster (Usually only used for dev purposes). So node ports are used for anytime you want to access a pod from outside of your cluster, but it only used for development purposes, load balancer are the right way to access a pod from the cluster.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: posts-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: posts
  ports:
    - name: posts
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
```

```
http://192.168.39.234:31154/posts
```

**31154** is the nodePort we got after creating the node port service.

[image]

**3. Load Balancer:** Makes a pod accessible from outside of the cluster. This is the right way to expose a pod to the outside world.

**4. External Name:**  Redirects an in-cluster request to a CNAME url.

Comment: Please don't post images when it's possible to post text. Images are not easily searchable and degrade the quality of a post. And you can't copy their content, which is a PITA when trying to work with a question or answer.